# javascript memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

i've just noticed that some javascript i;ve just written appears to be leaking memory, it quite a simple piece of code - thanks to jquery - but I can watch it running in taskmanager and the memory usage is slowly clicking up by between 4 and 40 bytes.

All i'm doing is throwing some data at a asp mvc controller/action via getJSON:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var olddata = "";
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var options = JSON.stringify({
            orderby: "name"
        });
        var params = {
            options: options,
            data: olddata ? JSON.stringify(olddata) : ""
        };
        $.getJSON("/Home/GetTasks", params, function (json) {
            olddata = json;
            json = null;
        });
        params = null;
        options = null;
    }, 1000);
});
```

I've bumped up the timer value just to see the problem more readily. I'm obviously doing something wrong here butcan't see what.

Should I be cleaning up the getJSON call?

TIA.

Comment: I'm currently doing a similar test. I have a simple html page making XHR call to another html page. It does no other processing, DOM manipulation or any scripting. What I've found is making XHR calls does cause memory to leak. Chrome leaks very very little, IE less and FF simply bleeds. Bottomline, doing Ajax will cause small increase in memory footprint in browsers.

Comment: One thing you can improve here is to move out the inline function from `setInterval`. Define it and instead use its handler in `setInterval`. It'll help alleviate the leak somewhat.

Comment: You could also stop redefining params and options every time the interval fires.

Comment: Would the memory increases of 4 to 40 bytes by any chance be roughly equal to the size of the JSON you're getting back each request?

Comment: @Mrchief and sciritai - both of the issues you pointed to should not result in a leak.  Local variables should be used and released when the function and anything keep it around as a lasting closure finishes.  You would be relying less on the browser garbage collection if all local variables were at the `$(document).ready()` scope (so there was just ever one copy of them), but that could also create a problem if the setInterval time was ever smaller than the getJSON response time such that two getJSON calls were in flight at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you know you're actually leaking memory?

At small numbers like 4 and 40 bytes, you could just be seeing heap growth, but some of the new blocks in the heap are "free" and available for future use so while the overall app memory use grows, the memory isn't actually leaking and will be available for future use so it won't grow forever.

If this is the entire extent of your experiment, then I don't see any issues with the code.

There are three function closures here.  The `$(document).ready()` closure lasts the lifetime of your code, but it's just a one-time deal so there should be no issue.

The anonymous function passed to `setInterval()` keeps the `$(document).ready()` closure alive.  Each call to the `setInterval()` anonymous function should be a new call that will get a new set of local variables and release it's old ones when the prior calls runs to completion.

The anonymous function passed to `getJSON()` creates a closure on the setInterval anonymous function, but that closure should only last until the getJSON function finishes and when it does the `setInterval()` anonymous function closure should be released.

The only closure that I see that lasts here is the `$(document).ready()` closure which is something you intend and it's only created once so it should cause no leak.

All the local variables in the getJSON anonymous function are going to be released when the it finishes.  The only data from the getJSON call that survives is your assignment of:

```
olddata = json;
```

But, each successive assignment is just replacing the data from the previous call so the previous data is no longer referenced and available for recycling by the garbage collector.

There are no DOM manipulations here so there is no opportunity for cross or circular references between DOM and JS.

My conclusion is that I don't see anything that will leak.  I see plenty of things using temporary memory so I suspect what you're seeing in the process memory usage is just heap growth, but growth in a way that the memory that has grown will eventually get reused.  If the browser is also caching the JSON results, you could be seeing memory cache growth too.

Unfortunately, in today's browsers, it's difficult to tell when it's really a memory leak versus a temporary expansion of browser memory used by caching, general heaps, etc...  In the extreme, you could set all caches to be very small and run this for a long time (hundreds of thousands of iterations).  If it's not a leak, memory use should eventually flatten out.  If it is a leak, memory usage should continue to grow relatively linearly.

**Disclaimer:** the one disclaimer here is that I'm assuming that the jQuery function `$.getJSON()` doesn't leak itself and always finishes in a way that cleans up the closure it creates, even if the ajax call is not successful.